# Can ICommand be use for simulating Combobox Selected Index Change or it is something else?

Tags: wpf, c#-3.0

If I want to write a custom command for a button control in WPF, I can go ahead with ICommand.

How about the case for Combo box Selected Index Change event? Is it possible to do the same using ICommand or something else will help me out?

Help need both in concept as well as a simple example(if possible) or a web link that will help in understanding the implementation part too.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to bind your view to your view model via MVVM.  To do this, you can't use an ICommand, but you can use a collection view:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.aspx

http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.com/2009/03/binding-combo-boxes-in-wpf-with-mvvm.html